# Page numbering of preliminary pages in thesis

Tags: thesis

In my thesis, I want to open all chapters on right including the preliminary pages, however, open=right command comes with a disadvantage of odd page numbering of preliminary pages (i.e. after title page there is a blank page and the dedication page appear with page no iii), which is not desired. Is there any way to open preliminary pages of thesis on right side but with customized page numbers. 
I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, open=right]{book}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,left=4cm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\sectionmark}
\fancyhead [R]{\nouppercase\leftmark}


\fancyhead[L]{}
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents,notoccite}

\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.8ex}}        
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{0pt}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
xxx
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{}
\input{dedication}

\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\input{acknowledgement}

.............
...........
\tableofcontents
.............
\mainmatter
\newcommand*\Newpage{\newpage\null\thispagestyle{}\noheader\newpage}
\mainmatter
\chapter{XXX}
\input{XXX}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1):

This is a revision of your MWE (which did have a problem).

```
% pagenumberprob.tex  SE 547685

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{book} % deleted open=right

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,left=4cm, includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\sectionmark}
\fancyhead [R]{\nouppercase\leftmark}


\fancyhead[L]{}
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents,notoccite}

\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.8ex}}        
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{0pt}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
Title is xxx
\end{titlepage}

\setcounter{page}{0} % PW added this
\chapter*{}
%\input{dedication}
Dedicated to ...

\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
%\input{acknowledgement}
Acknowledging ...
.............
...........
\tableofcontents
.............
\mainmatter
\newcommand*\Newpage{\newpage\null\thispagestyle{}\noheader\newpage}
\mainmatter
\chapter{XXX}
%\input{XXX}
The chapter's text

\end{document}
```

The significant change I made was

```
\end{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{0} % I added this
\chapter*{}
Dedicated to % instead of \input{dedication}
```

which then makes the page number of the dedication be "i", which is what you appear to want.

If you had processed your MWE it would have come up with the notice that the global option `open=right` was unused; there is no such option for the `book` class, the default is that chapters start on righthand pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any distinction between preliminary pages and main content you can remove the `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commands.

PS: when you upload a source code put 3 grave accents (```` ``` ````) on the line before and after and specify it's a `tex` source, example:

````
```tex
code here
```
````

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I require page numbering in "roman" for preliminary pages and "arabic" for the main matter. Either of: customizing the margins of preliminary pages or customizing the page numbering of preliminary pages can serve the purpose.